# Bash for ... in loop continue to previous item

Tags: bash, for-loop

I want to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for var in a b c d e f; do
    read -n1 $var
    [[ "${!var}" == "d" ]] && continue the_previous_item
    echo ${!var}
done
```

But:

1. `continue` only accepts integers.
2. `continue` (AFAIK) doesn't have a **previows item** option.

Is there any proper solution/workaround/hack to do this?

Comment: This would create an infinite loop, just saying. But you could always store the last value in a separate variable...

Comment: Can you explain what you want in english instead of pseudo-bash?

Comment: @thatotherguy: Now explained in pure and old-school bash (except the `continue` part the code runs).

Comment: ``continue`` just jumps to the next iteration of the loop. It does not make sense to pass an integer to it. Can you just explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @RamboRamon Nesting. `continue 2` continues the other loop in two nested loops.

Comment: Is the question "How do I repeat the current iteration of a loop?"

Comment: @Siguza Thanks for enlighten me. It is really hard to find information about shell built-ins. The man pages are not that helpful.

Comment: @RamboRamon: they are, but it takes time to get used to it. it's all there. `man bash`.

Comment: so in this example, what's the "previous item"?

Comment: You aren't using `var` in the body at all, and don't have any apparent variables for `${!a}` to refer to.

Comment: @chepner: Sorry, pseudo-code typo. Check now.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I want to continue to the previous iteration (repeat the current iteration)

Comment: if you want to read value again if it was (lets say:) wrong, you can simply use a 'while' loop with 'read' inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what behaviour you expect. Does this solve your problem?

```
for var in a b c d e f; do
    while [ 1 ]; do
        read -n1 $var
        [[ "${!var}" == "d" ]] && continue
        break
    done
    echo ${!var}
done
```